# Where to put code that create multiple objects after one is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry, code-organization

It is a question about how to organize code, I can't decide what is best and I did not find clearly what would be the best practice in the following case:

I have model A. After create, I need to create 3 models B, 4 models C, and an undefined number of model D, all related to model A.
My code work as expected, it is really a question of where should I put the code to do all of that.

For now, in the model A controller's `create` action, after model A save, I have 4 services that handle all the logic. But when I `rails db:seed`, I have to repeat the call to these 4 services. So I am tempted to put these 4 calls in an `after_create` callback on model A, but isn't this breaking the single responsibility pattern?
In addition, I have a fifth service handling the notifications, which I don't want to put in the model callback, so I don't get lots of notifications every time I `rails db:seed`.

Maybe what I did is already correct, and following best practices, but I am unsure about that, and I need confirmation or opinion from you, kind readers.

*PS: sorry for the English :-)*

Comment: Why don't you have _one_ service that knows how to build A and its dependencies, then just use that in your seed?

Comment: I was going to do this if the model callbacks turn to be a bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

You doing right, because with scalability of your application callbacks become a headache. Little article why better avoid callbacks.

> http://codeatmorning.com/3-reasons-to-avoid-rails-callbacks/

Comment: Thank you for pointing to the famous callbacks hell, I did not thought about this but yes it can get messy. But this means that when an other developer create a model A, he need to remember to call the services.